# GameController -[_GCControllerManager setupHIDMonitor:] crash in iOS 14

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Recently, we are getting "`GameController - [_GCControllerManager setupHIDMonitor:]`" crash in our live app very frequently only in iOS14, attached is the stack trace screenshot.

We didn't find any information on this so I posted here to get help from you to diagnose this crash.

Also, we don't have anything related to `GameController` in our code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because the h5 container is using `UIWebView`, so it's causing crashes. I recommend you switch from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`. After you change, you can slowly observe if the number of crashes has decreased. If there is a drop, then it means that UIWebView causes the problem.